# Bitcoin mining: internet connection status?

Tags: mining-pools, mining-profitability

How much bandwidth consumption can I expect per 13 Thash/s rig (Pooled). I'm Buying an s9 antminer, and i live in lebanon ( bad connection ).what do u guys advise me to do?
Does the internet speed affect ? What the speed required in order to mine correclty? How much data does it use monthly ?
Note: Assuming that i ll mine 24/7 
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, For solo mining a fast internet connection DOES matter, but in the case of a pool, it's a lot less.

> On Stratum with variable difficulty, you should need ~1kbps (0.125 KB/sec).  It doesn't matter how fast you are, which is why the new protocols were implemented.  1 GH/s, 1 TH/s, 1 PH/s, with proper server implementation it should all use the same bandwidth per connection.`

You should need barely any bandwidth for pool mining. If you watch packets between your rig and the server, they make up a very small amount of data 
(1-10kb?) The requirements are extremely small for most of them. This would be ~10 MB per day.

It also depends on the pool you're going to mine on.